# Sort string array in PHP by a number parsed parsed from each string

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a program where I receive a string at the input and store it line by line in the field, for example list [0] = 'Roll 5CZK', etc .. I also have a function that finds the value from the string (number, here 5). How can I sort this field. I don't want to solve it with a 2D array

```
$string='Rohlík 5Kč
CZK400 Knížka
Pivo 42,-
Houska 4 Kč';
$list = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);

getPrice($list[1]); // => 400
getPrice($list[2]; // => 42
```

Comment: There's a [list of sort functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). Pick the one you need. Without knowing what `getPrice()` is doing I can't tell which one fits best. There is nothing wrong with creating a helper array to sort it out.

Comment: Sure, I can create an auxiliary field and then compare, but I wonder if it's easier. The function (my written one) returns the numerical value from the string, I tried to indicate it in the code.

Comment: Something like this `usort($list, fn ($a, $b) => getPrice($a) <=> getPrice($b));`? Though note that, `getPrice` might be called repeatedly for the same element. If that is a problem you should map to some intermediary data structure, sort and map back afterwards.

Comment: But I can not understand the problem. What exactly do you want to sort? Can you please refine your question and add the expected result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with usort as in the comment, only $a and $b swapped to achieve a descending sort.

```
$arr = array (
  0 => "Rohlík 5Kč",
  1 => "CZK400 Knížka",
  2 => "Pivo 42,-",
  3 => "Houska 4 Kč",
);

/*
 * This is a greatly simplified implementation of getPrice()
 * to make the code reproducible
 */
function getPrice($str){
  return preg_replace('~[^\d]~u','',$str);
}

//Sorting
usort($arr,function($a,$b){
  return getPrice($b) <=> getPrice($a);
});

// Test Output
var_export($arr);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'CZK400 Knížka',
  1 => 'Pivo 42,-',
  2 => 'Rohlík 5Kč',
  3 => 'Houska 4 Kč',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

`foreach ($list as $v) $arr1[$v]=getPrice($v);`
`rsort($arr1);`

... and you are done!

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: @Ostermiller: of course, old fellow.

Why it works? I don't know. Perhaps it's a question of 1 and 0.
How it works? See above.

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your answer to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice.  Editing updates into your answer ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to use your answer sees them.